# Replicate chrome://offline-internals/ functionality - chrome.send is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, es6-promise

I am trying to build a [chrome://offline-internals/](http://chrome://offline-internals/) functionality. The chrome://offline-internals/ shows among many things, the pages which are stored for offline viewing, and this feature are only available in mobile chrome browser.

The page at chrome://offline-internals/ basically has a HTML page which I found using [view-source:chrome://offline-internals/](http://view-source:chrome://offline-internals/). I the HTML a javascript is referenced (offline_internals.js), which in turn has nested javascript referenced. I downloaded all referenced javascript in my local folder since chrome doesn't allow access to chrome://resources/js for referencing js pages.

After downloading, I tried to open HTML page and I got an error as below

```
cr.m.js:107 Uncaught TypeError: chrome.send is not a function
    at sendWithPromise (cr.m.js:107)
    at OfflineInternalsBrowserProxyImpl.getStoredPages (offline_internals_browser_proxy.js:30)
    at refreshAll (offline_internals.js:64)
    at HTMLDocument.initialize (offline_internals.js:248)
```

This basically comes in a file called `cr.m.js` in the below function

```
export function sendWithPromise(methodName, var_args) {
  const args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  const promiseResolver = new PromiseResolver();
  const id = methodName + '_' + createUid();
  chromeSendResolverMap[id] = promiseResolver;
  chrome.send(methodName, [id].concat(args));   <-- Error
  return promiseResolver.promise;
}
```

I tried to open [chrome://offline-internals/](http://chrome://offline-internals/) and set my breakpoint at the above function and that time `chrome.send` was found to be a function and when I ran my custom HTML page having same source and references, it says `chrome.send` is not a function.

Probably, the `chrome` instance given to my script vis-a-vis the one given to [chrome://offline-internals/](http://chrome://offline-internals/) is a different one.

What can I do to resolve this issue ?

**P.S.:** This link [chrome://offline-internals/](http://chrome://offline-internals/) will open in your mobile chrome browser only.

**P.S.:** All downloaded files are present at this path, in case you wish to see:
https://easyupload.io/9x332s

Comment: @PatrickEvans any tips ?

Comment: chrome://offline-internals/ doesn't seem to load on my desktop chrome or mobile chrome (ios). Other than that, the `chrome.send` JS APIs are typically built for internal Chrome pages & for extensions to talk to each other.

Comment: you will not be able to access functions like chrome.send unless you do chrome developing and create internal page with a custom webui. the only chrome functions you can use are [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/) if of course you are building a chrome extension, nowhere else.